# Terminology for A line Pattern that Doesnt Cross

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I am looking for terminology to the line pattern that we can draw connecting certain points such that the lines doesnt cross. Is there such a name?

Comment: A [planar graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph), perhaps?

Comment: +1 yes, thats it. Thanks!

Comment: @JhonnyS since nobody has chosen to post an answer based on that, and it solves your problem, you are welcome to post an answer yourself, and if in a few days there are no further issues, to go ahead and accept it as well. That lets future readers know that an answer has been posted an accepted. Without an answer, and with 0 up votes (I've fixed that) the question eventually disappears by the roomba bot, so it's always good to ensure that reasonable questions get answered one way or the other.

Comment: @uhoh thanks for the comment. Will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @player3236's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852438/terminology-for-a-line-pattern-that-doesnt-cross/4030611#comment7947409_3852438) *who chose not to post as an answer*, the term is: [Planer Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph)

> In graph theory, a planar graph is a graph that can be embedded in the plane, i.e., it can be drawn on the plane in such a way that its edges intersect only at their endpoints. In other words, it can be drawn in such a way that no edges cross each other. Such a drawing is called a plane graph or planar embedding of the graph

Comment: Since this has appeared in the "Low Quality Posts" review queue and reviewers can see comments, it is worth it to mention that this it the OP answering their own question **because they were encouraged to do so**, yet somehow got negative response because of it. To the OP: I have balanced out the votes, and it is spelt "Planar".

Comment: @player3236, I really appreciate that.